# cloth goes inside collision object

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation

I am making the "cgboost" apple bownl tutorial.
my fabric goes inside the bowls faces,not just on that.how to solve the problem?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cloth collision with an object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/101535/cloth-collision-with-an-object)

Comment: @J.Doe
unfortunately the answer didn't help me.it is a different case.
 :-(

Comment: Then please explain how your case is different. First make shour yo didnt miss any step of the tutorial. If your problem persists explain what you have done and where your problem occurs.

Comment: finally I solved.  :-D
the problem was because of an option in collision-the bowl-. the options name is single sided.it had to be unchecked.
it is checked by default.and it was making this problem.
the version of my blender is 2.82.

Comment: Nice to here! Dont be afraid to answer your own Question ;) write an answer and mark it as correct. So this question gets closed.

Comment: Thanks dear J.Doe