# How to get my two objects move natural (trebuchet)?

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging, objects, physics

so I've been working on two types of trebuchet. Following youtube tutorials got me this far:

1 trebuchet is working with a spoon at the end, but the launching object keep falling of even before it launch. ( I did add collision to the trebuchet and made the object active..

here's a screenshot: [image: screenshot at frame 0-1]
screenshot a few moments later: [image: at frame +/- 6]

The second model is:[image: without spoon]
How do I get this to work ( the sling has a cloth physics)

[image]

Comment: Please share your file via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Comment: The arms are working tho :)

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=YGgnXLzm" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/YGgnXLzm/)

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/101535/cloth-collision-with-an-object

Comment: Thanks ! I'll check it out today