Question on creating a dynamic cloth scene to create a medieval style bathtub
I'm trying to get a piece of cloth wrapped inside and around my bathtub. Here's an example image.  but no matter what I do, I can't get the cloth to sink in the middle of the barrel instead it just covers it. I even tried using a sphere with collision/gravity to collide with the cloth. I tried using rigid body and soft body for the sphere, but nothing happens. The best I can get out of it is that it sits on top of my cloth. I've also adjusted the weight of the sphere to see if that was an issue.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/101535/cloth-collision-with-an-object/

Thank you @DuarteFarrajotaRamos for the helpful post. I went through the suggested steps and I'm still running into the same issue....It looks like it can't be done in the new blender. I'm trying the suggestion for the new blender but its crashing my blender without any reason to be honest with you...I'm not running out of memory when I try it....
